# Room - Get Object with MAX(numUsage)

Tags: java, android, dao, android-room

I am using Android Studio with the Room Lib and have a small problem.
My entity class has a value called "numUsage" (Integer)
But I don't know how to write my DAO-Query to get the LiveData of the one row/entry with the MAX/MIN(numUsage)

So basically I wanna know Object/entry with the highest and lowest number.

F.e.
Entry Number. 1 has 5 numUsage Points
Entry Number. 2 has 2 numUsage Points

And I wanna get all the information of entry number 1 - because it has the highest points.

I tried something like

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE (SELECT MAX(numUsage) FROM subscriptions)")
LiveData<Sub> getTopSub();
```

But this is seems to be wrong because I always get an error (that what I return is a null-object)

I am using LiveData because while using the App you can give the entries more numUsage Points so this is to keep track to it.

Maybe this is a rather simple question but I just cannot find a fitting answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an idiomatic way of getting the row with max/min value. In your case for example,

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM subscriptions ORDER BY numUsage DESC LIMIT 1")
LiveData<Sub> getTopSub();
```